# NodeJs in importing files in Create React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I know that NodeJS is important when using npm to download modules but does react depends from it? For example i have a react app created from create-react-app and i have this part:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
```

Is nodeJs used to configure the paths in the files or is it just the babel compiler that does that?

If yes, is babel configured to look in the node_modules files like NodeJs does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel is unaware of modules. It is the responsibility of a bundler (Webpack in create-react-app) to handle module imports.

Webpack [resolver](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/) works similarly to Node resolver regarding `node_modules`, this can be [configured](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules).

Comment: So nodeJs is only useful for npm modules?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's altogether useful. Webpack is Node tool. You wouldn't be able to use tools written in JS from command line without Node. React doesn't depend on Node. Build tools do.

Comment: I mean tha Nodejs is useful only from the command line like using npm downloading packages

Comment: Yes, it's useful for command line but command line is used for many things, like building React app. When you start an app with `npm run start`, it runs Node. You may take a look on what exactly CRA does by ejecting a project with `npm run eject` or checking CRA internals, https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts . It's basically Webpack+Babel+Jest template, all of these tools use Node.

Comment: " It's basically Webpack+Babel+Jest template, all of these tools use Node" you mean that Webpack+Babel+Jest HAVE tools that depend on Node and not Webpack+Babel+Jest  themselves depend on Node right? And one last thing: When downloading from npm packages like redux, npm saves them in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\. How webpack knows this location?

Comment: No, they are the tools that depend on Node (more specifically, Webpack and Jest are these tools, and Babel is just used by Webpack). You install npm packages to project directory that has package.json. And run Webpack (`npm run start`) from this directory. So it accesses node_modules that exists in this directory. If you run `npm run start` outside project directory, it would exit with an error.

Comment: Okay so ,Webpack and Jest cant run without Nodejs? C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\ is outside of my project directory where i run the  npm run start command.

Comment: Yes, they can't. Why did you go to AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\ ? It's for TS internal stuff. I wouldn't expect it to run your app under normal circumstances. I checked it locally, and it has its own package.json. This means that when `npm run start` runs in this dir, it will check https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#scripts section for `start` script. So it cannot know anything about your CRA project, unless you installed a project in this dir by mistake. I'd suggest to go away from CRA a bit and check how Node works for tooling, e.g. with some simple Webpack setup.

Comment: Okay i will check that. As for the AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\ path, the only thing i did was run npm redux --save and saved it in this location. My app works fine but i dont understand why it put it there

Comment: A lot of CLI tools are sensitive to current working directory, i.e. a directory you run them from. It put it there because you run `npm` in this dir and it updated the nearest package.json it could find. There's package.json in AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\ . A dir that has package.json is considered Node project root.